# Strange UISwitch layout issue in tableview Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I am having a strange issue with displaying a switch in a dynamic tableview: one of the UISwitch instances is aligned to the left. As soon as it is switched, it goes back to normal...for a while.

**Reproduction of the issue**
I can reproduce the issue on a physical devices and simulators for all types of devices. The row where the problem occurs depends on the screen size of the device: it seems to be the first row that is invisible at the start. On small devices row 8, on larger iPhones row 10 or 11. When I scroll, the same row is affected.

Screen shot:
 [image]

My code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return woordeninlijst.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! WoordTableViewCell

    cell.woordLabel.text = woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].naam
    cell.hulpWoordLabel.text = woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].hulpWoord

    var scoreImage = [0: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "score grijs"), 1: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "score oranje"), 2: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "score geel"), 3: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "score groen")]
    cell.score1.image = scoreImage[Int(woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].score1)]
    cell.score2.image = scoreImage[Int(woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].score2)]
    cell.score3.image = scoreImage[Int(woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].score3)]
    cell.score4.image = scoreImage[Int(woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].score4)]
    cell.score5.image = scoreImage[Int(woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].score5)]

    let activeSwitch = UISwitch()
    cell.accessoryView = activeSwitch
    activeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WoordTableViewController.switchChanged(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    activeSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    activeSwitch.isOn = woordeninlijst[indexPath.row].isActive

    return cell

}

@objc func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch!) {
    print("Switch value is \(sender.isOn)")
    print("Switch item is \(sender.tag)")

    let changeWoord: WoordMO = woordeninlijst[sender.tag]
    if changeWoord.isActive == true {
        changeWoord.isActive = false}
    else {
        changeWoord.isActive = true
    }

}
```

Any help is incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Wow thanks for helping out with improving my question Uday!

Comment: I would suggest to move the UISwitch creation to WoordTableViewCell's `awakeFromNib` (or `initWithFrame`: if you don't have a .xib / .storyboard) method, instead of recreating it for every cell. I'm not sure how it would fix/affect the problem but it *might*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggenstion CloakedEddy. Problem persisted. I have eventually rebuild the switch: instead of making it an accessory view, I have created a switch in Storyboard, which fixed the problem.